# Former2 keep loading resources in chrome

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to fetch a role using Former2 from AWS IAM service. But when I am clicking on Roles tab it keeps loading. I even pasted the name of the role which I need, it is showing that role below but all in grey area and keeps showing the loading image. Please see the ss below. Any idea why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

[image: Former2 keeps loading image]

Answer (score 0):

The IAM listing is probably the most intensive operation in Former2 as it does include users, roles, policies, managed policies etc. This can take a few minutes as the call rates can be throttled by AWS themselves.

If you still don't have success, feel free to [raise a bug](https://github.com/iann0036/former2/issues) in the GitHub repo, including any specific errors you might see in the browsers JavaScript console (in Chrome, this is at View > Developer > JavaScript Console).